# Laravel: Send Data to Controller via AJAX Without Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I need to send data via JS to a Laravel controller on a button click. I'm not using any form because the data is being created dynamically. 
Every time i try to send the data, i get an Internal Server Error (500), but unable to catch that exception in the controller or the laravel.log file.

Here's what i'm doing:

Route:

```
Route::post('section/saveContactItems', 'SectionController@saveContactItems');
```

Controller:

```
public function saveContactItems($id, $type, $items, $languageID = "PT"){ ... }
```

JS:

```
$('button').on("click", function (evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    var items = [];
    var id = $("#id").val();
    var languageID = $("#languageID").val();
    var data = { id: id, type: type, items: JSON.stringify(items), languageID: languageID };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/section/saveContactItems",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        processData: false,
        success: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i accomplish this?

**UPDATE: Thanks to @ShaktiPhartiyal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43214377/1880662) (and @Sanchit's help) i was able to solve my issue. In case some else comes into a similar problem, after following @Shakti's answer i wasn't able to access the data in the controller. So, i had to stringify the data before sending it to the server:**

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Comment: When you are using POST, you have to pass `csrf_token` field ...

Comment: @sanchitGupta i've tried that to, but was unsuccessful too...

Comment: Okay... Lets try with @ShaktiPhartiyal answer below.... and let me know if its work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to use

```
public function saveContactItems($id, $type, $items, $languageID = "PT"){ ... }
```

You have to do the following:

```
public function saveContactItems()
{
    $id = Input::get('id');
    $type = Input::get('type');
    $items = Input::get('items');
    $languageID = Input::get('languageID');
}
```

and yes as @Sanchit Gupta suggested you need to send the CSRF token with the request:

Methods to send CSRF token in AJAX:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

If you use this approach you need to set a meta tag like so:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

or

```
data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "id": id
        }
```

**UPDATE**

as @Sanchit Gupta pointed out use the Input facade like so:

```
use Input;
```

Comment: I can finally access the controller action :) Now i get the following error: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found'. This is caused by $id = Input::get('id');

Comment: Use `Input` facade at top of your controller

Comment: Solved the error, but the data comes up is empty. This is what i'm sending to the controller: Object {id: "5", type: "email", items: "[]", languageID: "PT"}

Comment: Its working! just needed to stringify the data before sending it to the controller: JSON.stringify(data);

Comment: Well Explained @ShaktiPhartiyal +1. Happy Coding :)